# How to draw text on screen using Directx?

Tags: c#, .net, directx

I have searched around the forums on google trying to work this out but I cant. I have done some tutorials on drawing primatives triangles, lines etc..  I now want to draw text, and maybe even textured text/fonts.  Totally stuck now, can someone post a snippet that allows me to do this in managed directx for c# please?

Answer (score 1):

```
using D3D = Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D; 
private D3D.Font text;
private void InitializeFont() 
{ 
System.Drawing.Font systemfont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12f, FontStyle.Regular);
 text = new D3D.Font(device, systemfont); 
}
```

for more information follow this link:[Displaying text using DirectX](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/Csharp/Series2/tut18.php)

Comment: I have actually tried that tutorial, but get an unhandled exception on line: text = new D3D.Font(device, systemfont); I had to change D3D to Direct3D though because there is no D3D reference

Comment: What version of DirectX are you using?

Comment: i used DX9 before,your  font name is valid?

Comment: i exactly use this code:private void InitializeFont()
{
System.Drawing.Font systemfont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12f, FontStyle.Regular);
text = new D3D.Font(device, systemfont);
}

Comment: I don't know what caused the error, there isn't any error before debugging/running, just an uncaught exception with no detail

Comment: Where did you get the reference D3D.Font? I have Microsoft.Directx and Microsoft.Directx.Direct3D only

Comment: using D3D = Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D; 
private D3D.Font text;

Comment: yes, I replaced D3D.Font with Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Font

Comment: witch version of directx u use?

Comment: Hi its Directx 9, I made a change and now it no error, but the direct isn't rendering. (none of my other shapes either).

Comment: Could you update your answer with a simple code with this working and maybe I Can see my mistake from that?

Comment: if you want upload your project and send me address,i will try to correct it

Comment: try this:http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/mdx_tutorial1/mdxtutorial1_src.zip

Comment: in  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) function in the end line use code"this.Invalidate();  "

Comment: and u did not use m_device.BeginScene();?you mast use m_device in onpaint fuction anter   "Graphics g = e.Graphics;"

Comment: No that didnt help unfortunately, also I forgot to put in m_device.BeginScene();, but that was a typo mistake not related to this error.

Comment: When you use that code are you seeing the text on the screen? Maybe my VS 2010 is not setup correctly?

Comment: if you can upload project file,i will check

Comment: can't you just put the code into your project? I Can't really upload the project

Comment: (I really appreciate your help so far, if that is all thank you very much, I need to go to sleep but I think your answer is right, I am making a mistake somehow so I will keep trying to learn and fix it, and tomorrow I will mark your answer as correct.)

Comment: you didnot use "  m_device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, 
                  System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255).ToArgb(), 1.0f, 0);"in on paint function

Answer (score 1):

If you're using DirectX 9, the link @irsog posted is a good tutorial, I've used it before and can verify the results. If you use DirectX 10, I recommend the following tutorial:

- http://rastertek.com/dx10tut12.html

Note that if you use DirectX 11, you are going to have some trouble. Microsoft removed Direct2D from DirectX 11, so you have to either call DirectX 10 APIs or create you own Font interface. Both options are explored here:

[How do you draw text in DirectX 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708860/how-do-you-draw-text-in-directx-11)

Comment: How do I find out which one I am using?

Comment: When you added the references to the DLLs, it should tell you the version number.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, thats going to be the version number of the particular version of DirectX, so that doesn't get us anywhere...
Where did you download DirectX from? Can you give me the URL of the SDK you downloaded?

Comment: It was the Feb and June 2010 SDKs I downloaded, but I dont know which one placed the DLLs in the windows folder

Comment: Either way, both of those SDKs are directX 9, so full credit to @irsog for the tutorial link. If you post a new question with some more code, it would be most specific and would probably get more answer :)

Comment: ok, so it seems I am maybe putting things in the wrong place :), thanks a lot I will try a fresh project again with no other code and see if I can recreate the result and post a new question.